# Can't get public IP address from ESP8266 using ipify

Tags: arduino, ip-address, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm using NodeMCU to use ESP8266 and I want to use ipify to get public IP address. 
But I get -1 on `httpCode`. Why is that?

If I type `api.ipify.org`, it gets my public IP address properly.

```cpp
void loop() {
  Serial.println(WiFi.status());
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
    Serial.println("az");
    HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");  //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                                                  //Send the request
    Serial.println(httpCode);  //<<---- Here I get -1
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code
      String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(payload);                     //Print the response payload
    }
    http.end();   //Close connection
  }
  delay(10000);    //Send a request every 30 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http.begin("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
```

You are using your HTTPClient to browse a HTTPS website (HTTP + SSL/TLS tunnel), but you're using the wrong `.begin()` call. The `begin(String url` call expects a `http://` URL, not a `https://`. If you want to securely browse the website using HTTPS, you need to use the function `begin(String url, String httpsFingerprint)` ([link](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp#L104)). You can find the needed `httpsFingerprint` by following [this guide](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2556#issuecomment-271372001). Using HTTPS will induce a whole lot of memory overhead and processing time, though. For the case of browsing a "what is my public IP" website, I would just advise to browse the `http://` version instead, since the response is not confidential information.

So, you could just do

```
http.begin("http://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
String getIp()
{
  WiFiClient client;
  if (client.connect("api.ipify.org", 80)) 
  {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
      client.println("Host: api.ipify.org");
      client.println();
  } else {
      Serial.println("Connection to ipify.org failed");
      return String();
  }
  delay(5000);
  String line;
  while(client.available())
  {
    line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(line);
  }
  return line;
}
```